# Should I enable Gzip on Nginx server with SSL for a react app?

Tags: reactjs, performance, nginx, frontend, gzip

I have a react app with a pretty large build size, it is deployed on an Nginx server with SSL. I learned a bit about GZip and how it can improve the site's performance. But I also came to know that it is not to safe to use GZip with SSL. 
GZip is enabled for HTML files by default in Nginx. Should I enable it for other files like Javascript and CSS as well to improve performance ?

Answer (score 9):

When you say

> it is not to safe to use GZip with SSL

i assume that you are talking about [Breach Attack](http://breachattack.com/#howitworks). Well for breach attack to be successful for the compressed response, two conditions need to be satisfied:

1. Reflect user-input in HTTP response bodies
2. Reflect a secret (such as a CSRF token) in HTTP response bodies

When you send compressed js/css files in response, you usually do not reflect user-input in the response. That means calling the js/css file url will only return that file.

Also you usually do not return any sensitive data in the response along with compressed js/css files.

So yeah it is completely safe to use Gzip compression for js/css assets. Static responses are not vulnerable to this attack.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have one more doubt, there is also an "application/json" type in gzip_types in nginx.config file. Should I keep it or remove it from here as you say that its safe to gzip only static assets?